# Windows 7's start menu's search "see more results" is broken

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, shell, start-menu, windows-search

After searching in my start menu and clicking to "see more results", I got an error dialog:

[image]

It **"seems"** that it should be search-ms:query=document an not search:query=document but where can I fix this?

Additional info:

- New user account don't have the problem.
- Windows 7 Ultimate - RTM
- Disabling/Enabling again "Windows Search" (in Start > Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features on or off) doesn't fix it.
- (There's a HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Search in my registry that's not there normally.) -> outdated see comments...

**Update**:

It could help me to diagnose, if someone send me any (hidden) files in %userprofile%\searches and some others pieces of registry:

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.search-ms
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.searchConnector-ms
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SearchFolder
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\SEARCH
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Search
- Any other related key that I don't have seen...

Comment: Are you using a full version or still a Beta release?

Comment: full version, i have updated my post...

Comment: Does a reboot fix anything?

Comment: reboot don't fix anything

Comment: what does the new registry setting contain? It's in my registry, and I've not experienced your problem (Win7 Pro)

Comment: In fact, It's normal, It's not a really reliable source that say me that he don't have a HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Search and Will, that I trust many more have posted exactly what I have in mine, so I think it's related to others registry keys. (I have already try to copy some related registry keys from a clean user but without success)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure whether you found a solution to your problem, but I had the same issue on my PC (running Windows 7 Pro 64 bit), and found the fix [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100318032509/http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/02aa1279-56d5-487f-9825-b62128f916d2#ce530e5d-0b73-46dc-8df3-394acb076db9) (copied below), specifically the part where it says change the registry key `SetupCompletedSuccessfully` to `0`.

> NOTE: Using this fix will reset all your search/indexing options and cause your index to be rebuilt.

---

Important: The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: How to back up and restore the registry in Windows

1. Press `Windows + R` (Opens the "Run" window)
2. Type `regedit` and press Enter.
3. In registry editor, locate

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search
   ```
4. In the right pane, right click on `SetupCompletedSuccessfully` and click on `Modify`.

   > NOTE: If `SetupCompletedSuccessfully` is not there, then in the right pane, right click on a empty area and click on `New` select `DWORD (32 bit)` Value and type `SetupCompletedSuccessfully` and press Enter.
5. Type `0` and click on OK.

   > NOTE: This is the number zero. Note that when you zero the value below, the system will erase all your parameters you entered in the index options, a.k.a. the directories you list. So you'll be back to default values.
6. Close Regedit
7. Restart the computer

Comment: Many thanks, I was hopeless and it worked! I would accept your answer but I can't... :( I don't know why, maybe because I have offer a bounty without accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

This article might contain the solution to the problem:

[Fix Search Association Settings in Vista](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-search-association-settings-in-vista/)

Although it is for Vista, it might still pertain for Windows 7. The article contains registry fixes, so I suggest to create a system restore point before applying this fix, just in case.

Comment: Doesn't work, still the same error: doesn't find search:query= ... Maybe I'm gonna transfer all on another account...

Comment: You can also use Process Monitor to try and figure out what is happening and so what part in the registry is wrong.

Comment: Compare this with another account.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what's happening with process monitor because explorer.exe is involved and I must use the start menu just before launching the shortcut. So I don't know how to set my filters rules, it's either too fastidious or too restrictive

Comment: Start PM first.

Comment: It's obvious, how can I see what's happening if PM is not started...
I'll try to explain again:
The problem is that my error, start menu, search & many other things are explorer.exe sub-process. And explorer.exe have so many events in PM that I don't know how to set filters properly. And I can't just launch the shortcut alone because it only appears after a search (= many events) in start menu (= many events)

Comment: One can search the output of PM. Start with another account, find search-ms, then compare with the bad account. If this is too much work, just abandon this account.

Answer (score 1):

I had a client with a similar issue, I exported the HKCR\search and HKCR\search-ms from a working machine and that seemed to fix it.

[I have uploaded the .reg file I used.](http://www.mediafire.com/?zwqygnn3kje)

Comment: Doesn't work, it's exactly what I already have in my registry...
Thx anyway

Comment: ok... I think I know what may be wrong then, I am to tired to try now, but please recheck my answer tomorrow and I will edit with another answer

Answer (score 1):

Without admin rights to access the registry, I used the suggestion of this link and fixed the issue: http://www.goodnerdhelp.com/unable-search-windows-7-windows-find-searchquerysummative-solved/

In accordance with the Stack Overflow tradition, I am copying the original content of above link in case it goes away in the future. The steps:

```
1st – Right click on the Windows Start button, and click “Properties”
2nd – Click “Customize”
3rd – Scroll down until you find “Search other files and libraries”. Move the radio
        button from “Search with public folders” to “Search without public folders”, 
        click “OK”, and click “OK” on the previously opened window
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a matter of user permissions, you go to the folder c: \ User \ yourouser and Right click mouse properties, click on security then changes and add a new user who will be called Everyone.
Press OK to numerous warnings.

Comment: Poor quality answer. there's no indication the problem is security or permissions